# Creating a concrete mix with smooth texture

Tags: concrete

I would like to create a small concrete table(~.5m diameter). To do so, I would like to create a concrete mix with smooth texture, similar to Quikrete. Since this product is not available where I live, I was wondering what is the mixture I should use to create the concrete. It's properties should be smoothness (no coarse aggregate), and durability.
I can reinforce it with still /GF if needed.
Any advice where to start?

Comment: The smoothness is in the finishing, not the mix. Garage and basement floors are very smooth when power trowelled, and they're full-aggregate concrete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isherwood's statement is correct in that basement floors are smooth but the surface is made smooth using a power trowel. A power trowel would be much too large to use for your application.

I suggest using an aggregate free Portland cement and sand (or silica powder if its available). The ratio is typically 1 part cement to 3 parts sand and water of course. The trick to getting a smooth final surface starts after its poured and before it sets. You will need to create or purchase a float that will be used to produce the smooth finish. After you've poured your mix into the mold, level it out and make sure no air pockets are below the surface.

Within a few minutes the setting process begins. This is when you will see a layer of water develop on the surface. Using your float, skim the surface in one direction until the desired smoothness is achieved. It's that simple!

Also, I suggest reinforcing your tabletop with steel. Chicken wire (as it's called around here) should work well or some other mesh type steel. Good luck and post some photos of your final creation!

Comment: +1, but "chicken wire" is extremely fine gauge. Is that really what you'd use?  I'd think some 2-4-12 or something would be better, but maybe if the chicken wire was folded back a time or two...

Comment: I've experimented with aggregate free cement, but it would not hold! I've made small batches of ratio of 1:1, 1:2 and 1:3 (cement:sand , +water) and they all crumbled in my hand. Did you actually tried this? all the recipes I've looked had some kind of aggregate. Did you add anything else?

Comment: @Mercury How long did you allow it to cure before testing? I'd imagine cure time could be longer, and that temperature could be more of a factor while the mix is setting. I'm also interested in a similar project for an outdoor potting bench.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at gfc, especially adding glass fibres to the concrete mix (increase structural strength with little weight) and a few add mixtures such as super six admix. I have been experimenting myself and the guidance given has been helpful and created nice results. They are prohibitively expensive here in the uk but looking to get cheaper. Ill be trying other, more available mixtures as i learn of other options.